# Ruby on Rails - undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have spent the past few hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but I cannot come to a solution.  Simply put, I am trying to populate a select box with data from a table called 'semesters'.  (I've seen tons of questions regarding this on SO, but I cannot get them to work with my app).

Here's what I have:

## Courses Controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @semesters = Semester.all()
   @course = Course.new(params[:course])
    # Save the object
    if @course.save
      flash[:notice] = "Course created."
      redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end
end
```

## View

```
#views/courses/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(:course, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.select(:semester, @semesters.map { |s| [ s.name, s.id ] }) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Create Course") %>
<% end %>
```

I was hoping it would output:

```
  <select>
    <option id="1">Spring 2013</option>
    <option id="2">Fall 2013</option>
  </select>
```

But instead, I am getting the error:

```
 views/courses/new.html.erb where line #32 raised:

      undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Line #32 corresponds to my form helper select.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: The error message says it all, `@semesters` is `nil`.

Comment: Can you post your `edit` action of `CoursesController`?

Comment: Also post the `new` action.  My guess is that you're not defining @semesters in that action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set your `@semesters` variable in controller:

```
def new
  @semesters = Semester.all
end
```

The error occurs because unset instance variable is evaluated to `nil`, so you try to call `map` method on `nil` object.

Comment: You're right.  I was accidentally setting it in the `create` action, not the `new` action.  Thanks.